# Convert function source code to a string in NodeJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I am creating JavaScript functions for map/reduce operations on database server side. To have syntax highlighting and errors check I make it like this inside my text editor:

```
var map = function (doc, meta) {
  emit([doc.type, doc.created], doc);
};
```

Then I need to somehow turn it into a string variable so that to add it as a view to Couchbase looking like this:

```
var map = "function (doc, meta) { emit([doc.type, doc.created], doc); };"
```

Is that possible to convert the source code to a string somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Function.toString` is your friend.

Try:

```
map.toString();
```

Comment: Not at all. Did you try it?

Comment: @SergeyBasharov Seem to work okay: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ8mp/ If it doesn't work for you, could you edit your question to explain exactly why?